# rootfs folder in yocto

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, rootfs

I have been using buildroot till now and recently switched to Yocto. In buildroot, the root file system is present in the "target" folder. What is the location of the root file system in Yocto. I know it will be in "build/tmp" folder and it is not "sysroots" folder.

Correct me If I am wrong.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Honister (Yocto 3.4/BitBake 1.52), you can use `bitbake-getvar` instead of `bitbake -e | grep ...`. Replace `$target` with your image name (e.g. `core-image-minimal`):

```bash
# Get variable name, value and history:
bitbake-getvar -r $target IMAGE_ROOTFS

# Get just the value:
bitbake-getvar -r $target --value IMAGE_ROOTFS
```

The last example is especially nice for scripting:

```bash
cd "$(bitbake-getvar -r $target --value IMAGE_ROOTFS)"
```

Answer (score 21):

You can find it with the following command:

`bitbake -e <image> | grep ^IMAGE_ROOTFS=`